# Different icons for different nodes in extjs

Tags: extjs

I want to show the parent child relation using the tree in extjs 4. I have table which contains three fields: `node_id`, `parent _id`, and `node_type`. Here node_id and parent_id representing the child parent relationship. node_type is 9 digit code for node. Based on this 9 digit code, I want to show the icon of the node in tree.

There is no problem in generating the simple three with default icons for node and leaf.

But I need help implementing the different icons for node based on that node_type 9 digit code.

Comment: Show us the code you have to far, more importantly instanciation and population of your tree class

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to add an appropriate css class value to iconCls field of the tree record. Or just return `iconCls` from server as a part of json.

Answer (score 0):

Use Saki's response if you have control over the server response and don't mind mixing the model and view domains. An alternative for keeping the view separated from the model is to use the [Load](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-event-load) event of [TreeStore](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) to map your `node_type` code to the corresponding css class `iconCls` on the `node` instance.